# NameNotFoundException when starting JBoss with an EAR using HornetQ ConnectionFactory via JNDI

Tags: jboss, jms, jndi, jboss6.x, hornetq

I am currently trying to deploy an app on JBoss 6.1 which has some JMS MessageListeners in it. The MessageListeners get the connection factory via `JNDI` (using Spring), I am using the `HornetQ` default connection factory which is named `ConnectionFactory`. I am currently just using the default `JMS Queues` that `JBoss` starts with: `DLQ` and `ExpiryQueue`

When I deploy via `JMX` the app has no problem starting.

When I deploy by copying the app in to the deploy directory and start the server the app will fail to start giving the following error message: `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ConnectionFactory not bound`. This implies to me that the app is starting before `HornetQ` starts and is available via `JNDI`.

I have looked in to creating dependencies using the `jboss-dependency.xml` however I have not been able to get this to work and I am not sure if this is even the correct approach.

How can I ensure that the `HornetQ` starts before my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered just this problem yesterday, the problem is caused by JBoss starting your application before it has registered the ConnectionFactory and Queues.

I found my application deployed perfectly from Eclipse which waits until after JBoss has started before deploying.

The solution is to modify the `server/{node}/deploy/jbossweb.sar/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml` file adding the following within the `WebServer` bean.

```
<depends>org.hornetq:module=JMS,name="NettyConnectionFactory",type=ConnectionFactory</depends>
<depends>org.hornetq:module=JMS,name="InVMConnectionFactory",type=ConnectionFactory</depends>  
<depends>org.hornetq:module=JMS,name="NettyThroughputConnectionFactory",type=ConnectionFactory</depends>
```

This worked for me and I found the solution here: http://edemmorny.com/2011/10/17/jboss-as-6-startup-connectionfactory-not-bound/

Comment: can you provide me complete jboss-beans.xml and kindly tell me the purpose of this file